# Null pointer exception when trying to access a widget on a dialog fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement fingerprint support to a dialog fragment. I followed a youtube tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI9TItdw83U&, but it had how to implement fingerprint on a new page and not a dialog.
        FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler (this);
The this is erroring out saying FingerprintHandler in FingerprintHandler cannot be applied to Biometric Activity.

I tried getActivity() instead of this but when I try to access a widget in the dialog, my app crashes but when I access a widget in the MainActivity, it works fine.

https://gist.github.com/EphraimB/f2c05184690a6aef9536a16b36ad509a

I expected FingerprintHandler to access and change the text in the DialogFragment but the app crashes and I get an error in the debugger saying that the FingerprintHandler getViewById(R.id.paraLabel) is changing text on a nullpointer.

Logcat message:

```
2019-05-15 11:08:53.163 11481-11481/com.example.paay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.paay, PID: 11481
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.paay.FingerprintHandler.update(FingerprintHandler.java:52)
        at com.example.paay.FingerprintHandler.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintHandler.java:45)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$AuthenticationCallback.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:304)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:1107)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.access$700(FingerprintManager.java:75)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:1030)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using and the logcat message

Comment: I posted the code in gist and shared the link.

Comment: Is your BiometricActivity a fragment?

Comment: Yes, it's a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the crash happens because you want to access a widget `R.id.paraLabel` out of activity view
please a add a TextView to your FingerprintHandler constructor

```
   public FingerprintHandler(Context context,TextView txt) {
    this.context = context;
    this.textview = txt ;
 }
```

and then in your update method use textview instead :

```
 private void update(String s, boolean b) {
    textview .setText(s);

    if (b == false) {
        textview .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
    }

    else {
        textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
}
```

and nullpointer  will happen to your imageview as well .

Comment: did you instantiate it in your class before using it ?

Comment: I just added TextView textview and it now works. Thank you!